Describe two people sitting across from each other at a coffee table on a rug
I want to describe two people sitting across from each other at a coffee table on a rug but I don’t know how to put it the right way
They are both sitting on a rug with the coffee table in between them, talking or doing something else. I want to say “A is sitting across from B at the coffee table on the rug” but I’m conflicted and thinking of whether saying it this way instead is actually the right one: “A is sitting on the rug across from B at the coffee table.”

You must make an attempt and post it, and point out the phrase  you are in doubt about.  Specific questions are answered here.

It depends if the primary thing is that they're on a rug or at a table or sitting facing each other. Which is most important?

I'd say they sat across the coffee table, both sitting on the rug.

Why do you want to describe this? Describing a scene is not a very common thing to do. In the rare case that you do need to describe a scene (for example to a police officer) you do so in a dialogue. If you are setting a scene for a story, why not use several sentences? Why do you need the detail about the rug and the coffee table.  This all seems like a strange thing to want to do.

TL;DR The best solution in my mind is this:

Amy and Brent are sitting on a rug with a coffee table between them.


Some general notes:

The situation itself is unusual, so no way of describing it will sound completely natural and unmarked. The main conflict arises from sitting on a rug combined with the idea of being at a table, which suggests sitting on a chair. It's difficult to form a clear mental image of the sitting posture and distance from the table without more detail.

Various orders of the prepositions are certainly intelligible and could easily be clarified, but some orders are more likely to yield the right interpretation.

There's no reason to feel bound to express this in a single sequence of prepositions. You can use more than one sentence or add a clarifying clause more easily than you can make this arrangement sound natural.


With those in mind, my preferred way to say this concisely is similar to what you first proposed:

Amy and Brent are sitting on a rug with a coffee table between them.


"with a coffee table between them" is much easier for me to parse than "Amy is across from Brent". Otherwise, if we separate Amy, we already have two prepositions describing her position ("on a rug" and "at a coffee table"), and this third one becomes confusing. More importantly, it's hard to construe them as "at a coffee table". The height and purpose of a coffee table aren't really suited to the word "at".1

"on a rug" best attaches to "sitting". Otherwise, it too easily wants to modify the table or the other person: "Amy is sitting at a coffee table on a rug" makes me assume she's on a chair (or sofa), while "Amy is sitting across from Brent on a rug" leaves me quite confused as to whether Amy, Brent, or both are on the rug.



1 One can, however, play card games or board games or what have you on a coffee table — a natural phrase, and the resulting image does not place the players on the table :)

Or "A and B are sitting on the rug at either end of the coffee table".

@KateBunting True, assuming it's oblong and they're are the ends — they could also be at the sides, or (unless OP were to insist on "at") not even adjacent to it.

Well, OK, 'either side' then.

They are many ways to describe the scene, sometimes adding more words makes the scene more interesting.


Angela and Bruce are sitting on a rug at opposite ends of a coffee table.


Presumably they are doing something  at the table, right? It could be chatting, playing cards, eating or drinking. It would be odd if the table was at a significant distance between them.


While sitting cross-legged on a rug, Angela and Bruce were chatting and giggling across a coffee table and two half-full wine glasses.



The situation can be accurately described by these sentences:
'1. A and B sit facing each other, on the rug at a coffee table.".
'2. A and B are sitting opposite each other, on the rug at a coffee table.".
'3. A and B sit facing each other on the rug across a coffee table.

Where do they sit? On a chair? On a stool? No, it's a rug.  "They're sitting on a rug facing/opposite each other"

@Mari-LouA I didn't understand your comment. A coffee table is a low table.

What do you mean, you don't understand? In many parts of the world people sit on chairs, stools, armchairs and sofas which can either be placed on a rug or just around it. A coffee table can be near a sofa, so people can read a coffee table book or  sip a cup of coffee/tea.
